# VMAX Architecture in UWP

Tags: uwp

When I want to generate the UWP Package, Visual Studio Shown this error for me.
[VMAX Architecture Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXrAD.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. The library you use is built as an ARM library (for phones) and you are trying to use it when running your app on the desktop (x86). So that is a ARM vs X86 mismatch.

Either switch your app to ARM and run it on phone or get a X86 version of this library.

Comment: But I Still not understand

Answer (score -1):

As @IgorKulman said, you are running the app using the ARM library which only works for phones. If you're debugging through visual studio, make sure to specify which resources to use under the run task. you should choose to debug x86 instead of ARM release.